# Background worker - report progress with string array

Tags: c#, .net, backgroundworker

I need to return multiple STRING values from my backgroundworker in each loop, so I tried to use ReportProgress second parameter as string array. Example of code:

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    string[] workerResult = new string[2];
    for (int i=0; i<someNumber; i++)
    {
        //do some heavy calculating
        workerResult[0] = "this string";
        workerResult[1] = "some other string";
        backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(i, workerResult) // also tried workerResult[] and [2]
    }
}

private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    string[] results = (string[])e.UserState;

    MessageBox.Show(results[0]); // line of error
    MessageBox.Show(results[1]); // line of error
}
```

It compiles, but on runtime in the moment I try to access Userstate returned string, I get an error: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

For me it seems lik something is wrong when passing array parameter to ProgressChanged delegate, or in ProgressChanged method when trying to set results array values.

Comment: Is there a deeper reason why you run `backgroundWorker2` but report on `backgroundWorker1`?

Comment: Also, why use an array of strings, versus a collection?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. Example was wrong, should be correct now.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Your code snippet is incapable of reproducing the problem.  A standard mistake is to call ReportProgress() and then to continue modifying the object.  It takes a while for the event handler to run, it will see the modified object, not the original.  You avoid this by simply creating a new object so that the event handler always works with the original.  Like this:

```
        //do some heavy calculating
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
            string[] workerResult = new string[2];
            workerResult[0] = "this string";
            workerResult[1] = "some other string";
            backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(i, workerResult);
        }
```

Note how the array creation statement is moved inside the loop.

Answer (score 9):

when you instanciate your BackgroundWorker, you'll have to set reportprogress to true:

```
worker = new BackgroundWorker { WorkerReportsProgress = true };
```

On the do work method you'll just need this:

```
 worker.ReportProgress(10, "Message");
```

Then something like this to catch the progress:

```
private void WorkerProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e) {
            if (e.UserState != null) {
                MessageBox.Show(e.UserState);
            }
        }
```

Comment: WorkerReportsProgress is already true, and I need to report MULTIPLE STRING values, returning one value works for me, but when I try to return array, I get an error.

Comment: Well, you just call multiple times the report progress: worker.ReportProgress(10, "Message1"); worker.ReportProgress(11, "Message2");

Comment: That kinda solves my problem, but also creates a new one, since I'm updating my progressbar on every ReportProgress() with progressBar.PerformStep().

Comment: if you don't want to update (if there's no progress for example) just pass the same progress on both messages, ex:  worker.ReportProgress(10, "Message1"); worker.ReportProgress(10, "Message2");

Answer (score 0):

I've solved a similar issue by adding a new `ProgressChanged` event listener to your background worker and block passing to the next loop if `ProgressChanged` not fired:

```
bool progressed;

backgroundWorker1.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(bw_ProgressChanged);
string[] workerResult = new string[2];
for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
    progressed=true;

    workerResult[0] = "this string";
    workerResult[1] = "some other string";
    backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(i, workerResult);
    while (progressed)
    {
       //you can add a thread sleep 
    }
}


void bw_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
     progressed = false;
}
```

Comment: you can also try using Monitor instead of while(progressed), in my case it didn't work for me!

Comment: sorry but no need to do all that just as sad by Hans_passant, all you have to do is insert string array instanciation inside the loop