# VC++ Problems using gumbo-query (linking error)

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, unresolved-external

I've got a VC++ project, and I'm attempting to use the extension of the gumbo-query library, found [here](https://github.com/lazytiger/gumbo-query). This library wraps/extends Google's gumbo-parser found [here](https://github.com/google/gumbo-parser). The following is the exact steps I've taken - I'm not very familiar with importing libraries, so I've done what I do to use the Boost libraries:

In Visual Studio (VS Community 2013), under the project settings -> Configuration Properties -> C/C++ -> General I have put the path to a folder that contains all of the source files from both of the projects linked above. Specifically, I placed the .c, .cpp and .h files from the src folder of both projects and referenced these in my projects settings as an include directory.

Following the example file for the project that extends Google's gumbo-parser ([found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5459205/background-worker-report-progress-with-string-array)), I added these two lines to import the library:

```
#include "Document.h"
#include "Node.h"
```

At this point, my solution compiles fine. However, continuing to follow the example file, adding the first variable declaration:

```
CDocument d;
```

Causes a linker error, as follows:

```
1>Main.obj : error LNK2028: unresolved token (0A0003B7) "public: __thiscall CDocument::CDocument(void)" (??0CDocument@@$$FQAE@XZ) referenced in function "private: void __clrcall MyApplication::Main::worker_DoWork(class System::Object ^,class System::ComponentModel::DoWorkEventArgs ^)" (?worker_DoWork@Main@MyApplication@@$$FA$AAMXP$AAVObject@System@@P$AAVDoWorkEventArgs@ComponentModel@4@@Z)
1>Main.obj : error LNK2028: unresolved token (0A0003B8) "public: virtual __thiscall CDocument::~CDocument(void)" (??1CDocument@@$$FUAE@XZ) referenced in function "private: void __clrcall MyApplication::Main::worker_DoWork(class System::Object ^,class System::ComponentModel::DoWorkEventArgs ^)" (?worker_DoWork@Main@MyApplication@@$$FA$AAMXP$AAVObject@System@@P$AAVDoWorkEventArgs@ComponentModel@4@@Z)
1>Main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall CDocument::CDocument(void)" (??0CDocument@@$$FQAE@XZ) referenced in function "private: void __clrcall MyApplication::Main::worker_DoWork(class System::Object ^,class System::ComponentModel::DoWorkEventArgs ^)" (?worker_DoWork@Main@MyApplication@@$$FA$AAMXP$AAVObject@System@@P$AAVDoWorkEventArgs@ComponentModel@4@@Z)
1>Main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual __thiscall CDocument::~CDocument(void)" (??1CDocument@@$$FUAE@XZ) referenced in function "private: void __clrcall MyApplication::Main::worker_DoWork(class System::Object ^,class System::ComponentModel::DoWorkEventArgs ^)" (?worker_DoWork@Main@MyApplication@@$$FA$AAMXP$AAVObject@System@@P$AAVDoWorkEventArgs@ComponentModel@4@@Z)
1>..{omitted}..\MyApplication.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 4 unresolved externals
```

This error appears to occur no matter where I put a CDocument instantiation.

What can I do to rectify this? VS seems to think the includes are fine, and moreso when I put in CDocument d; it lights up to show it recognises the CDocument type.

Comment: That is not a compilation error but a linking error. You may need to include
all the classes from that gumbo-parser in  your Visual Studio project so that those classes will be compiled and can be used during linking.

Comment: Do you mean I need to include more of the .h files in my project? I noticed that the two .h files I'm already including in their own code include all other required files, it seems.

Comment: not really include but add those files, both .h and .cpp, in your project workspace in Visual Studio.  That way it will be compiled.

Comment: I may try that, although that seems odd considering my current approach works fine for the Boost libraries. I notice all of my files for this library are correctly found under External Dependencies folder in the solution explorer.

Comment: The problem with adding all of the .c, .cpp and .h files into my project is that: "cannot compile C file '\attribute.c' with the /clr option" pops up for many of the files.

Comment: I am compiling that library in VS2010 as well. did you already compiled the gumbo C as the one you are trying to compile now ia just a warppe

Comment: https://github.com/google/gumbo-parser

Comment: I haven't compiled any libraries or anything - I've just added the directory containing the src files of both projects to my include directories in VS. I've not actually done this before, so I simply did what I've done when I've imported Boost.

Answer (score 2):

As always, it's clear I've been a JS developer for too long. I really did need to compile a .lib file. Thank you to [Christian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/480386/christian) for reminding me of this.

The original gumbo-parser project by Google includes a VS project. I opened this and compiled it, fixing all of the project settings problems so that I could import it into my project, which I did via the Configuration Properties -> Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies setting for my VS project.

Next, I added the extra source files from the wrapper library gumbo-query, where I had to fix a naming conflict between parser.h/parser.cpp from the original gumbo-parser project and the Parser.h/Parser.cpp file in the wrapper library. I also changed all references to `#include <gumbo.h>` to `#include "gumbo.h"`

Eventually, I got a gumbo.lib file containing both the original and the wrapper libraries, and this imported into my project and I now seem to be able to successfully use the functions.