# How do i make backgroundworker reportprogress more then once from a different vars?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I added to form1 top a string array:

```
string[] stringProgressReport;
```

Then in one event i did:

```
private void videosInsertRequest_ResponseReceived(Video obj)
        {
            string r1 = stringProgressReport[0] = obj.Status.UploadStatus;
            backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(0, r1);
        }
```

Then in a second event i did:

```
private void videosInsertRequest_ProgressChanged(IUploadProgress obj)
        {
                string r2 = stringProgressReport[1] = obj.Status.ToString();
                backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(0, r2);
        }
```

Then in backgroundworker progresschanged event:

```
private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = 
            toolStripStatusLabel2.Text =
        }
```

The Label1 i want to get the e.UserState of the first array report index [0] and the second Label2 from index [1].

e.UserState dosen't have any indexs option to give.

EDIT

In my DoWork event i have allready:

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            UploadVideo(FileNameToUpload, uploadVideoTitleTxtBox.Text, uploadVideoDescriptionTxtBox.Text);
        }
```

And the UploadVideo method:

```
static Video video = null;
        static ulong process = 0;
        private void UploadVideo(string FileName, string VideoTitle, string VideoDescription)
        {
            UserCredential credential;
            using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(@"D:\C-Sharp\Youtube-Manager\Youtube-Manager\Youtube-Manager\bin\Debug\client_secrets.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                    GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                    new[] { YouTubeService.Scope.Youtube, YouTubeService.Scope.YoutubeUpload },
                    "user",
                    CancellationToken.None,
                    new FileDataStore("YouTube.Auth.Store")).Result;
            }
            var youtubeService = new YouTubeService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                ApplicationName = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name
            });
            video = new Video();
            video.Snippet = new VideoSnippet();
            video.Snippet.Title = VideoTitle;
            video.Snippet.Description = VideoDescription;
            video.Snippet.Tags = new string[] { "tag1", "tag2" };
            comboBox1.BeginInvoke((Action)(() =>
            {
                video.Snippet.CategoryId = (comboBox1.SelectedItem as ComboboxItem).Value.ToString();
            }));
            video.Status = new VideoStatus();
            video.Status.PrivacyStatus = "public"; 

            using (var fileStream = new FileStream(FileName, FileMode.Open))
            {

                const int KB = 0x400;
                var minimumChunkSize = 256 * KB;

                var videosInsertRequest = youtubeService.Videos.Insert(video,
                    "snippet,status", fileStream, "video/*");
                videosInsertRequest.ProgressChanged +=
                    videosInsertRequest_ProgressChanged;
                videosInsertRequest.ResponseReceived +=
                    videosInsertRequest_ResponseReceived;
                videosInsertRequest.ChunkSize = minimumChunkSize * 4;
                videosInsertRequest.Upload();
            }
        }
```

And from this UploadVideo i'm registering the two events: videosInsertRequest_ResponseReceived and videosInsertRequest_ProgressChanged that i show in my top of my question.

And from this two events i want to report to the progresschanged event of the backgroundworker.

What i did now in the DoWork event and the progresschanged event is:

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            UploadVideo(FileNameToUpload, uploadVideoTitleTxtBox.Text, uploadVideoDescriptionTxtBox.Text);
            for (int  i = 0; i < stringProgressReport.Length; i++)
            {
                backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(i, stringProgressReport);
            }
        }

        private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            string[] labelsreports = (string[])e.UserState;
            toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = labelsreports[0];
            toolStripStatusLabel2.Text = labelsreports[1];
        }
```

I didn't get any errors or exceptions but it didn't update the toolStripStatusLabel1 and 2.

Comment: Take a look at the following post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5459205/background-worker-report-progress-with-string-array

Comment: David tried now this solution in the post i also edited my question to show where i register this two events that i want to report from them to the backgroundworker. Now i'm not getting any exceptions but it dosent update the toolStripStatusLabel1 and 2 Text.

Comment: I need to report from inside this two events somehow to the backgroundworker since the code will first work with this two events untill they finish upload the video file. So the loop i did in the DoWork it never get there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, you have a background worker thread that is executing code that can raise either of two different kinds of events for which you want to report progress. The `ProgressChanged` event handler in turn needs some way of updating the appropriate label for the given string.

It seems to me that the simplest way to get the code to work is to just update both labels regardless of which underlying event occurred:

```
private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = stringProgressReport[0];
    toolStripStatusLabel2.Text = stringProgressReport[1];
}
```

You may want to initialize the `stringProgressReport` elements to something reasonable so that until the event corresponding to that index has actually been raised, some reasonable text is still displayed (and so you're not assigning `null` to the `Text` property).

If you wanted to be more "surgical", you could pass the appropriate index as the `userState` parameter (instead of a `string` value as you do now):

```
private void videosInsertRequest_ResponseReceived(Video obj)
{
    stringProgressReport[0] = obj.Status.UploadStatus;
    backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(0, 0);
}

private void videosInsertRequest_ProgressChanged(IUploadProgress obj)
{
    stringProgressReport[1] = obj.Status.ToString();
    backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(0, 1);
}

private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    int eventIndex = (int)e.UserState;

    if (eventIndex == 0)
    {
        toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = stringProgressReport[0];
    }
    else
    {
        toolStripStatusLabel2.Text = stringProgressReport[1];
    }
}
```

That would allow the `ProgressChanged` event handler to update just the label relevant to that particular update.

There are of course many other approaches you could take that would work equally well, including variations that don't require the use of the `stringProgressReport` array at all. But either of the above options should work for you, as well as give you a little better insight into how these event handlers can work together to achieve the effect you want (i.e. so you can implement other variations as needed).